# Set cookie to not be visible for subsites

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm setting cookies with JavaScript, one on site 1 and one on site 2, both with the same name.  The problem is I'm getting the cookie that was set from site 1 on site 2, if I set the cookie on site 1, the navigate to site 2.

Site 1 domain is `a.b.c.d.com/somepage.html`
Site 2 domain is: `a.b.c.d.com/somefolder/apage.html`

Is there a way to set cookies on Site 1 that won't be available in site 2 and vice versa?

Comment: your sites are simply sub-directories of the same `a.b.c.d.com`? if you don't want 'em shared, then set a path on the cookies.

Comment: So, would you set the path on site 2 to `/somefolder` and site 1 wouldn't be able to read it?

Comment: exactly. e.g. `document.cookie = "somefolderonly:nyeah_cant_see_me; path=/somefolder";`

Comment: So...seems like if you only change the second sites cookie to have a path, the first site's cookie will still be visible on the second site.

Comment: @MasterN8 That's correct. You can define context visibility, not exclusive visibility for each path. That means that if you set a specific path you are saying that the cookie should be visible for all virtual directories starting from the path you specified.

Comment: I have done a similar research a few months ago to document the behavior of the "domain" attribute, see https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/pull/91.

Comment: Thanks for your input all...I think the solution for this situation is going to be using different cookie names for Site 1 and Site 2.